# How to tell if a float is SNAN or QNAN

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, ieee-754

I am trying to figure out how to print out if a floating point number is QNAN or SNAN. I have already separated out the bits into the signBit exponentBit and the FractBits.

```
unsigned int sign = (i & 0x80000000) >> 31;
unsigned int exponent = (i & 0x7f800000) >> 23;
unsigned int fraction = (i & 0x007FFFFF);
printf("signBit %d, expBits %d, fractBits 0x%08X\n",sign, exponent, fraction);
```

Comment: You can get *some* help from the [common mathematical functions in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math), You can also determine if a type have the different NaN types using [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Comment: IEEE 754 doesn't define the binary format of specific NaNs. The existence and format of signaling NaNs depends on the platform (usually, hardware and OS).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GNU [provides](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Floating-Point-Classes.html) a facility which was [recently](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1778.pdf) [standardized](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=63146):

> Macro: `int issignaling (float-type x)`
>
> Preliminary: | MT-Safe | AS-Safe | AC-Safe | See POSIX Safety Concepts.
>
> This macro returns a nonzero value if x is a signaling NaN (sNaN). It is based on draft TS 18661 and currently enabled as a GNU
>   extension.

The final draft TS mentions that you might need to opt-in with a macro to get it:

> ```
> #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__
> #include <math.h> 
> int issignaling(real-floating x);
> ```

Comment: Some platforms have `fpclass()` / `_fpclass()` which is similar to `fpclassify()` except it differentiates between quiet and signaling NaNs.

Comment: @cremno It looks like that's not the route taken by ISO, though. The TS only acknowledges that it will "provide  the  facility  of  the  class  function  recommended  in  the  Appendix  to  IEC 60559  (except  that  the  classification  macros  defined  in  7.12.3  do  not  distinguish  signaling 
from quiet NaNs)." (IEC 60559 the successor to IEEE 754.)

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to mention it as not everyone is using glibc and there doesn't seem to be another (open source/public) implementation of it yet.

Comment: Looking at the implementation of `numeric_limits::*_nan()`, I find that the two return values are `7FFF40...` and `7FFF80...`. But *any* non-zero significand is a NaN in IEEE-754, so there seem to be lots of NaN values that are neither signalling nor non-signalling. Maybe there's just a single "signal" bit (namely the highest bit of the significand)?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: in fact, IEC 60559, born IEC 559, standards are the same as IEEE 754, just issued by another Standard body with a different cover letter, but otherwise identical contents; ISO committee WG14 uses IEC references only because of ISO politics; IEC 60559:2011 is the same as IEEE 754:2008, and they are substantial revisions (successors) of IEC 559:1989 / IEEE 754:1985. What is important here are the revisions.

Comment: @AntoineL https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/343 . The only thing more incredible than the politicisation of such rubber stamps is that we allow ourselves to be inconvenienced to research and discover that they're really meaningless.

Answer (score 6):

The format of the floating-point real numbers is processor-dependent. On x86 / x86-64 ISA, the top bit of the significand = 1 for quiet, 0 for signalling.   (The rest of the NaN payload is still arbitrary).

- `float` type:

  [image]
- `double` type:

  [image]
- `long double` type (not supported by Microsoft compilers):

  [image]